# Issue using Amazon Cognito Identity in us-west-1 (N. California) Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I tried to use cognito identity with a bucket in us-west-1 (N. California), however it's not work. I got a region error.

Then I did create a new bucket in us-west-2 (Oregon), and it's works as expected.

The weird thing is that both pool id are like "us-west-2:xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx". I expected that pool id from bucket in us-west-1 shows a pool id in format "us-west-1:xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxx".

Does anyone know why this happens?
Does work cognito with buckets in us-west-1 region?

Comment: What was the exact error? Most likely, it was due to a configuration issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito is currently not available in the us-west-1 region, but it is in the us-west-2 region. Hence, explaining why it worked as expected when you created a new bucket in the us-west-2 region.